# PhpStorm - How to type hint array key correctly?

Tags: php, arrays, phpstorm, phpdoc, type-hinting

There is still an open issue about how to annotate array keys with PhpDoc: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/650

I tried the following notations:

```
/**
 * @return array<string, SomeClass>
 * @return SomeClass[string]
 */    
public function someMethod(): array { ... }
```

but PhpStorm seem to be unable resolve this appropriate, so that when using e.g. 
 `foreach` the inner object is unknown:

```
foreach($obj->someMethod() as $some) {
   $some->methodOfSomeClass(); // PhpStorm -> Method not found
}
```

I know i can use the pipe operator:

```
@return array<string, SomeClass>|SomeClass[]
```

I also know that i can type hint variables:

```
/** @var SomeClass $obj */
$obj
```

But is there a way to configure PhpStorm to know the array value type without using the pipe?

Comment: Either inline using `@var` when that array element will be used (when assigned to some variable) -- see Code Spirit answer .. or try **deep-assoc-completion plugin** (it allows detailed description for array parameters/returns) -- https://github.com/klesun/deep-assoc-completion/blob/master/README.md

Comment: *"array<string, SomeClass>"* -- AFAIK PhpStorm may only parse this syntax (not showing warnings; not 100% sure on this) but does not actually understands it. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43843 and possibly https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20193

Comment: Types such as array<int, Exception|Foo> or type array<string,string> now supported and parsed since phpstorm 2020.3 EAP #2

Answer (score -2):

In PHP you either have numeric indexed arrays which have integer keys or associative arrays with string keys. Due to the dynamic typing you can just mix these up and therefore can have both types.

Also in your example you are not using your key but the value, these are hinted with `ClassName[]`.

```
/**
 * @return Class[]
 */
function getClasses(): array {
  return [new Class()];
}
```

With this typhinting PHPStorm will provide valid tooltips in forEach loops.
Otherwise you can use the inline `@type` comment.

```
foreach ($objs as $obj) {
  /* @type Class $obj */
  $obj->someMethod(); //Is hinted
}
```